# ORACLE pass user defined object type as parameter to procedure

Tags: oracle, procedure

I am trying to attempt a bulk insert by using a FORALL in the Procedure .

I have tried the below steps to create the procedure :

```
**CREATE TYPE SECID_TABLE as TABLE OF VARCHAR2 INDEX BY NUMBER;**

CREATE PROCEDURE ASP_STOCK
(**p_secid IN SECID_TABLE**
) as
BEGIN
..
END;
```

But the above two statements do not compile. I am rather new to oracle and use aqua studio which doesnt seem to be verbose on the error statement.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: "the above two statements do not compile." What is the error message? Does it just need a `/` character on a new line after the `CREATE TYPE` statement? Do you really need to use an associative array or can you remove the `INDEX BY NUMBER` clause and use it as a collection?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

The first problem is that you can't create an index-by table with an index type of `NUMBER`. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b305/1)  Change the index type to `PLS_INTEGER`.

But even if you do THAT you're still going to get errors because an index-by table like this is a PL/SQL-only construct. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ccaec3/1).

You're going to have to do something else. Try an unindexed TABLE type, which is allowed at schema level. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89b07/1)

Best of luck.